# POSIX unnamed semaphore sem_init() between two programs

Tags: posix, semaphore, shared-memory

I'm not quite sure how you would share the semaphore using only `shm_open()` and `sem_init()` since the manual doesn't say how the semaphore relates to the shared memory.

EDIT:

I'm trying to communicate two processes with 4 blocks of shared memory controlled by a total of 3 semaphores and used by 3 threads in the producer program and 2 in the consumer side.

I have a program that does just that but in the same program using named semaphores and with two blocks of memory (6 chars each), 3 threads for producer, 3 for consumer.

Basically, I want to achieve this: https://pastebin.com/mvx20aRG
With shared memory between two distinctive consumer and producer programs.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What have you achieved? Please, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Wikiti You are right. I just added an explanation :)

Comment: *how the semaphore relates to the shared memory*? They are not related to anything, you can use any semaphore for what you want. Using one for a given shared segment is just an agreement.